# Openlayers commercial application: licensing issues?

Tags: google-maps, open-source, licensing, openlayers

I am planning on creating a commercial fleet/asset tracking web app, but got discouraged when I found our about the high price Google and Microsoft charge to use their services in a commercial setting. I found Openlayers, and it claims to be free, so I am wondering if anyone has had experience using it commercially?

I looks like the use of the API is free, but does that include the maps as well? Openlayers also lets you use Google as the mapping provider, but if I do that, would I be breaking Google's TOS since it is commercial?

I apologize if this isn't the correct place to ask such a question as it isn't directly related to a programming problem, but I can't find a definitive answer anywhere else and I imagine someone on SO has had experience creating a commercial mapping application.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OpenLayers has no data - it is an opensource mapping API that can be used with many different data sources.

To be free of all data licensing concerns use OSM data rather than Google - http://www.openstreetmap.org/ with OpenLayers. See some examples at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers#Examples

Answer (score 1):

Depending on usage, you'll probably want to provide your own map server rather than rely on (for example) a free OSM one. These can provide the data (including map tiles) that OpenLayers uses to draw its maps.

UMN MapServer and GeoServer are popular. I've found MapServer combined with OpenLayuers a powerful combination.

I've never used GeoServer, but I think it requires serverside Java. And there are other options.